# How to permanently change var?

Tags: javascript

So, I have a var set in a function and a array(called "card_idx) set up, and I want the var be set to 0 until a certain number is reached in the array but the number doesn't go up in order (1..2..3..4 extra). It jumps around depending on how the person plays ( so it can be like...1...2...2.1....5....3.2...). And I want the var to be set to 0 until a specific number is reached and then it is changed to 1.

I try having it set up like:

```js
 var x=0;
if(card_idx == 3.2){
x=1
}
```

but the moment there no longer on 3.2 it will change back to zero,  how do i make it so it will stay 1?

Comment: your question is quite unclear, please elaborate more and add some more code.

Comment: if card_idx >= 3.2? 
Not sure if I understand you correctly though..

Comment: It sounds like you need to scope the 'x' variable in your example differently so it retains it's value, but it's impossible to tell without a more complete example.

Comment: If your description of the problem and your code snippet match up, you're referencing your array in your if statement, not a value within the array. If that is the case, your array will never be equal to 3.2 therefore your variable will never be set to 1.

Comment: From what you have shown above, if card_idx == 3.2, x will be one inside and outside of your if statement. Sounds like you are dealing with a scope issue and you may need to include more code for a better answer. E.g. how card_idx is being generated, and the function this code is in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Use an extra boolean to check if `x` has ever been set.

Be aware that your variables are outside the iteration.

```js
var x = 0;
var hasSet = false;   

// start looping 
if (card_idx == 3.2 && hasSet = false) {
  x = 1
  hasSet = true;
}
```

Or maybe (if your question was more clear) this will work out too.

```js
var x = 0;

// start looping 
if (card_idx == 3.2 && x <= 0) {
  x = 1  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your example isn't complete enough to reproduce the problem, I imagine you may be running into trouble with variable scope.

JS variables are locally scoped to the function surrounding them, which works to your advantage here. If you declare `x` at the beginning of the function that goes through your data, the loop can modify it and the value will be retained after the loop completes:

```
function crunch(data) {
  var x = 0;
  data.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.index === 3.2) {
      x = 1;
    }
  });
  console.log(x);
}
```

If any `item` in `data` had an `index` of `3.2`, `x` will be set to `1` and printed to the console at the end. The callback to `forEach` grabs `x` using closure, but this would work just the same with a `for` loop.

Using `x` within the loop, the value will not be reset until `crunch` returns. Every time `crunch` is called, `x` will be set to `0`, may be set to `1` if an item has the right index, and will retain that value until the end of `crunch`.

Now, with `forEach`, if you were to declare `x` *inside* the loop callback rather than in `crunch`, it would reset every time:

```
function crunch(data) {
  data.forEach(function (item) {
    var x = 0;
    if (item.index === 3.2) {
      x = 1;
    }
  });
}
```

Because `var` operates at the function level, this will *not* keep its value and will be `0` for every item.

Comment: The var is called secrets and when ur on car 13.2 its set to be 1, but will change back to 0 the moment you leave 13.2, I want it to stay 1 once you've been on 13.2

Comment: @jakekin yeah, you just need to declare `secrets` outside of the function. It's a local variable, you want it at the script level or higher.